# tfs 2017 Adding a png to a workitem attachment using the REST API

Tags: javascript, attachment, tfs-workitem

I am trying to create an attachment for a workitem in TFS 2017. I found the "createAttachment" method in tfs REST API.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/workitemtracking/restclient/workitemtrackinghttpclient2_2#method_createAttachment

I was able to make this method work for text files. But what I need to do is create an image attachment. I have access to the byteArray content of the file and the base64 content of the file. But when I try to pass the byteArray I get the following error : "405 Method Not Allowed".
If I pass the base64 content of the image, the attachment is created but the image is not valid.

Here is the code I am using :

```
images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) 
   {
   var client = _RestClient.getClient();            
   var byteString = atob(blobInfo.base64());

   client.createAttachment(byteString).then(function (item)
      {
      console.log(item.url);
      });
   }
```

I need to find a way to create png attachment for a tfs workitem from inside a javascript custom control extension.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work by setting the processData parameter of the Post request to false. See the code below :

```
var byteString = atob(blobInfo.base64());
var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) 
   {
   ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
   }

$.ajax(
  {
     type: "POST",
     contentType: "application/octet-stream",
     url: SERVER_URI + "_apis/wit/attachments?filename=" + blobInfo.filename() + "&api-version=1.0",
     data: ia,
     processData: false,
     headers:
        {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(":" + TOKEN)
        }
  }).always(function (data)
  {
     console.log(data.url);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you need to upload the image in **binary form without base64 encoding**.

As the message said "`405 Method Not Allowed`", you can not create png image.

Howerver you can try to upload the png attachment to the attachment store, then attach it to the work item.

1. [Upload an attachment](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/attachments#uploadanattachment) and the sample code : [C#
   (UploadBinaryFile method)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-dotnet-samples/blob/master/ClientLibrary/Snippets/Microsoft.TeamServices.Samples.Client/WorkItemTracking/AttachmentsSample.cs#L49). (*Note that you need to upload the
   image in binary form without base64 encoding.*)
2. [Add an attachment](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#add-an-attachment) and the sample code : [C# (AddAttachment
   method)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-dotnet-samples/blob/master/ClientLibrary/Snippets/Microsoft.TeamServices.Samples.Client/WorkItemTracking/WorkItemsSample.cs#L547)

And this article may also helps : [Insert an inline image into a Work Item with the TFS API](https://roadtoalm.com/2014/12/31/insert-an-inline-image-into-a-work-item-with-the-tfs-api/)

---

**UPDATE:**

We can not create the png file, we can only upload the existing png file and attach it to the work items.

[image]

Comment: The method I call uses the same service. My problem is with the string I must pass. I am not passing the base64, im passing the binary. If I pass the base64 the file is created, but not in a valid png format. I updated my question with the code I am using.

Comment: @BadShift I tested the method with C# on my side, it works as expected, Javascript also should be working.  We cannot create the png even if the create action works but it's an invalid png format. See the updated answer.